# 4 by 4 Matrix Puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, puzzle

I was solving the puzzle for the Company interview exam. I found this puzzle, I cannot come up with the solution. How to solve it and what is the correct answer?

> Determine the number of $4\times 4$ matrices having all entries 0 or 1 that have an odd number of $1$s in each row and each column.

Comment: What company asks these questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fill the upper-left hand $3\times 3\,$  **arbitrarily**  with $0$'s and/or $1$'s. This can be done in $2^9$ ways.

For any such choice of $0$'s and/or $1$'s,  fill in the first three entries in the fourth row, and the first three entries in the fourth column, so that the number of $1$'s in each of the first three columns, and in each of the first three rows, is odd. This can be done in precisely one way.

Now put a $0$ or a $1$ in the lower right-hand corner, to make the number of $1$'s in the bottom row odd. It turns out that this makes the number of $1$'s in the rightmost column odd. To check this, work modulo $2$.

Comment: So,what is the final answer .Is it 2^9 ?.Also ,can i generalize this for k*k square Matrix.

Comment: Yes, the answer is $2^9$. And it does generalize.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Also,I have doubt,is there any general formula if the matrix is n*m ,where n not equal to m.

Comment: In general, there are $2^{(m-1)(n-1)}$ solutions if $m-n$ is even, and no solutions if $m-n$ is odd.  The basic strategy should be unchanged.